# Django ModelAdmin queryset throwing an error: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression

Tags: django, django-admin, django-queryset

I have this ModelAdmin class:

```
class CoachAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    actions = ['add_50_credits']
    list_display = ('number_of_clients_bought')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(CoachAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        qs = qs.annotate(models.Count('sale'))
        return qs

    def number_of_clients_bought(self, obj):
        return Sale.objects.filter(coach=obj).count()
    number_of_clients_bought.admin_order_field = 'sale__count'
    number_of_clients_bought.short_description = 'Clients bought'

    def add_50_credits(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(account_balance=F('account_balance') + 50)
        self.message_user(request, "50 credits added.")
```

The add_50_credits action was working properly before I added the get_queryset and number_of_clients_bought functions. But now when I try to use the add_50_credits action, it is throwing this error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/people/coach/
only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression
```

This line is throwing the error:

```
queryset.update(account_balance=F('account_balance') + 50)
```

Please explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how do I solve this issue, because right now I'm stumped. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where and how you call add_50_credits

Comment: It's an admin action, so it's called by selecting a coach in the admin then selecting the "Add 50 credits" action from the dropdown and hitting "Go".

Answer (score 0):

Guess....your queryset when entering add_50_credit func is bigger than 1.

Try to debug it there, print it when entering the func or pdb (beark point),

how about ....

```
def add_50_credits(self, request, queryset):
    for q in queryset:
        q.update(account_balance=F('account_balance') + 50)
        self.message_user(request, "50 credits added.")
```

just make sure the the message func get the correct request

Comment: Thanks, but this just throws a "Coach object has no method update" error. Update needs to be called on a queryset.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a problem with SQLite not being able to figure out which field to update because of the joins.

It's documented [here.](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18580)

I solved it by adding .values('id') to the operation, as follows:

```
def add_50_credits(self, request, queryset):
    queryset.values('id').update(account_balance=F('account_balance') + 50)
    self.message_user(request, "50 credits added.")
```

Note that 'id' is the default primary key for a Django model. If you have some other primary key for the particular model, you may need to use that one.